# How to get GeoJSON format from geometry data of SQLServer ?

Tags: c#, sql-server, geojson

I've got geometery data in a SQL Server database. My goal is to get it into GeoJSON format that my C#/ASP.NET server can offer to the client.

What are my options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I apologise for my misunderstanding your question because of lack of information. But as I understood, your need is that your server can gets the SQL data into GeoJSON?

I would suggest [GeoJSON.NET](https://github.com/jbattermann/GeoJSON.Net) from github for your server to get the data in GeoJSON.

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking for.